# Principal component analysis with censored data

Tags: r, pca, censoring

I would like to estimate an underlying linear relationship between two variables x and y.

There is significant error in both the x and y measurements, making linear regression inappropriate. However, the error in both x and y should be from the same (normal) distribution, meaning, I think, that ordinarily a principal component analysis should give an unbiased estimator of the underlying relationship.

My problem is that the data is also censored for both x and y below a certain threshold, i.e. there are "non-detectable" measurements. My question is how best to perform a principal component analysis on data censored in this way?

Thanks for any help, solutions provided in R would be great and below is some example R code generating data similar to the data I'd like to analyse:

```
# Simulate data for x
x <- rnorm(200, 1, 2)

# Underlying relationship between x and y
m <- 0.5 # Gradient
c <- 3   # Intercept
y <- x*m + c


## Simulate measured data
# Measured data has error in both x and y
measured_x <- x+rnorm(length(x))
measured_y <- y+rnorm(length(y))

# Data is measured to the nearest integer
measured_x <- round(measured_x)
measured_y <- round(measured_y)

# Data is _censored_ below 0 i.e. at <= -1
measured_x_cens <- measured_x
measured_x_cens[measured_x_cens <= -1] <- -1
measured_y_cens <- measured_y
measured_y_cens[measured_y_cens <= -1] <- -1

# How to best estimate underlying parameters m and c
# from measured_x_cens and measured_y_cens?
```

Comment: Look at Deming regression applied when the two variances are equal.

Comment: Thanks, Deming regression indeed looks like the right approach here, or orthogonal regression in this case.  I'm just not having much luck finding examples of how to apply it to censored data.  Perhaps I should repost the question under Deming regression with censored data?